A question about psychology of old patients of psychiatry
My question is Can I post about the psychology of old patients of neuroscience or psychiatry.  Is this normal that they don't want to hear about problems, solutions of cognitive sciences? I am an enthusiast.  Earlier I was a user of this site. This is not to suggest about my own problem or about doctors. Are nuclear radiation harmful to the hearts and brains of numerous patients including me? Though I know there is no physician-patient relationship.

As long as it's not a self-help problem or describes case reports of individual patients, in other words if your post has broad scientific value, I guess it's fine. Can you post an outline of the proposed question(s) here for us to look at?

@AliceD - Outline examples on proposed questions may normally be okay but with this question asking for that could be problematic. (See my answer)

Earlier I was a patient of psychiatry. But the question is not about my problem with cognitive sciences. user-37920


Can I post about the psychology of old patients of neuroscience or psychiatry.

The answer to that is
It depends on what you are posting.
Below are a few examples of when it is okay and when it is not.
If you are posting background details of your client
I think any qualified person here would know that the answer to that question is a definite no.
Any posts on StackExchange which detail any client background in any shape or form with or without the client's name must be deleted from the site
This is to respect client confidentiality from our side, and to protect any client from possible effects of such a breach of confidentiality.
Just because a name real or not is provided or not, doesn't mean your client cannot be identified by the background information.  You may be talking about one person, not identified, but someone may read it and assume it is someone else they know by a couple of small details they know and read into it that the rest of the details are fact about that person they know.
It is just not ethical.
If you just post something like, for example, "based on my experience with PTSD a high state of alert is often found"
That is fine.
It is all down to the issues of ethics and patient confidentiality.
All therapists and clinicians must have a confidentiality agreement that absolutely no details about the client is to be discussed outside the group of people dealing with the problem. In the case of one-to-one therapy, that means only the therapist.
Nothing is to be discussed in social media, or by any other communication method with anyone else.
There are very few exceptions
There are if course legal reasons you as a therapist might need to disclose details to a member of authority such as the Police, but only what is absolutely necessary.
You may need to speak to their General Practice Doctor about an issue your client raised, but that must only be with their permission.
There is only one other reason I can think of where you may need to discuss what is necessary to seek professional advice on a difficult problem for example and that is only to be done via clinical supervision and only if it is one-to-one supervision with a trained clinical supervisor. Clients must not be discussed in peer group supervision sessions.
So to reiterate:
No details that could possibly identify any specific individual is to be allowed on StackExchange just as it should not be anywhere else on the internet.
Any posts found to be possibly breaching client confidentiality MUST be closed and deleted from the site.
